# Creating Own DID Number

Tags: asterisk, sip

I have 2 Asterisk Servers installed in different machines. Lets say I have created 3 extensions: `101`, `102` and `103` in the first server.

Generally we can have a single call connected for one extension.

What I want to do is use the extensions of first server as `DID`, and one of these DID lets `101` to be used as `DID` number using `SIP Trunk`.

Ultimately, I need to have multiple concurrent calls, how can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have a SIP ITSP, and a DID of 123-567-8900 and your extension 100 is SIP device "local-phone-100", you might do something like:

```
[public]
 exten => _1235678900,1, Dial(SIP/local-phone-100)
```

For more detailed help, you'll need to edit your question to include the dialplan you have currently created so we can see what you've done.

*For further reading, please see:
[Asterisk: The Definitive Guide (3rd edition)](http://www.asteriskdocs.org/)*

*if this answer was valuable to you, please 'accept' it and upvote it so others in the community with a similar question can find it*